# Three.js rotate globe to a specific location periodically

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to rotate my globe every x seconds to a certain location. However, if i try to put render() into a for loop with a setTimeout, it will just run the whole thing in one go and not do it each time.

I suppose is something related to the recursiveness of render() but i was wondering if anyone had this issue before and how to solve it?

thanks!!

```
var lat=41.9028;
var long=12.4964;
var requestId = 0;
var targetx=lat * ( Math.PI / 180 );
var targety=(270 - long ) * ( Math.PI / 180 );

//i would like to repeat this periodically every x seconds
render(targetx,targety);

function render(tx,ty) {
    controls.update();
    sphere.rotation.x += (targetx - sphere.rotation.x) * 0.1;
    sphere.rotation.y += (targety - sphere.rotation.y) * 0.1;
    clouds.rotation.x += (targetx - clouds.rotation.x) * 0.1;
    clouds.rotation.y += (targety - clouds.rotation.y) * 0.1;
    var verticalOffset = 0.1;
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    requestAnimationFrame(function(tx,ty){render(tx,ty)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `requestAnimationFrame` wrong in your code sample above. If you want a 60FPS animation, you don't need to wrap `render()` into another function, since this might lead to infinite recursion issues. Simply do this, and you'll automatically get a 60-frame per second render call:

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

You also don't need to pass `tx, ty` arguments to `render()`, since they're not being used.

If you want to update only once every second, what you're looking for is `window.setInterval()`:

```
// i would like to repeat this periodically every 1 seconds
// Second argument is the delay in millisecs
window.setInterval(render, 1000); 

function render() {
    controls.update();
    sphere.rotation.x += (targetx - sphere.rotation.x) * 0.1;
    sphere.rotation.y += (targety - sphere.rotation.y) * 0.1;
    clouds.rotation.x += (targetx - clouds.rotation.x) * 0.1;
    clouds.rotation.y += (targety - clouds.rotation.y) * 0.1;
    var verticalOffset = 0.1;
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    // You don't need requestAnimationFrame, since you're not doing 60FPS
    // requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

// This updates target rotations 
changeTarget() {
    targetx = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    targety = Math.random() * Math.PI;
}
```

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for documentation on how `window.setInterval` works.

Comment: thanks for the correction. i have 2 issues tho:
- not using requestAnimationFrame(render) inside the render function, will not have a smooth animation
- i would need to have a different coordinates at each interval

Comment: Then I'm confused, because you asked to repeat `render` periodically every "x" seconds. With `setInterval`, you can manually control how much time passes between each render: longer times = rougher animations. If you want constant 60FPS animation, then ignore `setInterval` and use `requestAnimationFrame`. (I added a function on how to update targets so they can be read from within the `render()` function.